# Does a cron job touch the output file

Tags: unix, cron, monitoring, io-redirection

I have cron job working in the form of:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.sh >> /tmp/script.out 2>&1
```

When redirecting an empty `echo`'s output and appending it to an output file the modification date changes.
My question is if in the cron's output file this occurs as well?

I would like to know this to verify when the file was last executed without having to write into the file on purpose.

Comment: Are you asking whether `/tmp/script.out`'s modification time is updated every time the cronjob runs?  Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: it should be easy to run and check

Comment: Yes because I am expecting that to happen as well even if no echo occurs. But it is not updated though.

Comment: @CMPSoares so, try "*/5 * * * *  touch /tmp/script.out", maybe your script doesn't output anything

Comment: Yes @pmod but doesn't it by default touch the file?

Comment: When the file doesn't exist, it is created (touched). When it exists it is not touched.

Comment: Oh that might  explain the confusion thank you @WalterA! Is it possible to make touch the file independently of if it has output or not? Or do I have to add a touch at the beginning of each cronjob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your script doesn't output anything, the output file is not "touched", i.e. modification time is not updated. But you can add "touch" explicitly in this case:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.sh >> /tmp/script.out 2>&1; touch /tmp/script.out
```

By the way, `echo` *empty* output is not really empty, it produces newline character (i.e. LF = line-feed) :

```
$ echo | hexdump -c 
0000000  \n
```

Answer (score 1):

(Already commented: When the file doesn't exist, it is created (touched). When it exists it is not touched.)

When cron is enabled (usr/password not blocked, no cron denied) I would trust cron. When you want to see if everything is working, you should get the lifebeat from your script (directory and permissions still valid, no ^M at the end of the shebang, no invalid changes or other dependencies that fail).
The best way is to call touch a file from your script.